# Equivalent of float128

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, arbitrary-precision

How to work with equivalent of `__float128` in Python? What precision should I use for `decimal.getcontext()`? I mean, is the precision specified in decimal places or bits?

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = # 34 or 128 ?
```

Is it possible to set the precision "locally" for a given operation, rather than setting it "globally" with `getcontext().prec`?

Per Simon Byrne comment, is it even possible to simulate `__float128` as defined by IEEE 754 with `Decimal`? What other options do I have in Python, if I wanted quadruple-precision?

Comment: I think you will find your answers in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Comment: @vaultah I consulted the documentation beforehand, yes, but I wanted to make sure I understood it correctly. I wanted to check if `.prec` really sets **decimal** places, for example...

Comment: `decimal` is an implementation of decimal floating point, so `.prec` is decimal places. This will give you different answers than `__float128`, which is a binary format.

Comment: @SimonByrne So with `.prec = 34`, I wont get the same result as computing with `__float128`? Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of `gmpy2`. In addition to wrapping MPFR, `gmpy2` also wraps GMP (for integer and rational numbers) and MPC (for complex arithmetic). Both MPFR and MPC use a binary representation compared to `Decimal` which uses a decimal representation.

Here is a quick example showing use of the equivalent of `float128`.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.ieee(128))
>>> gmpy2.get_context()
context(precision=113, real_prec=Default, imag_prec=Default,
        round=RoundToNearest, real_round=Default, imag_round=Default,
        emax=16384, emin=-16493,
        subnormalize=True,
        trap_underflow=False, underflow=False,
        trap_overflow=False, overflow=False,
        trap_inexact=False, inexact=False,
        trap_invalid=False, invalid=False,
        trap_erange=False, erange=False,
        trap_divzero=False, divzero=False,
        trap_expbound=False,
        allow_complex=False)
>>> gmpy2.sin(gmpy2.mpfr("1.2"))
mpfr('0.932039085967226349670134435494826026',113)
```

For the 2.0.x series, `gmpy2.ieee()` only creates contexts for supporting 32, 64, or 128-bit formats. The development branch supports are wider range of precisions.

Comment: Btw., do you happen to know just how much slower IEEE soft float128 is compared to hardware double precision?

Comment: @EcirHana I'd start by assuming 10x slower but it depends on the operation. I can run some benchmarks later.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Python has native support for only one single floating point type, the double type of the underlying architecture.

Depending on the architecture, numpy can declare a float128, but it is known not to be consistently available.

If you need it outside of numpy, (or on a platform where numpy does not support it), you could have a look the the [bigfloat package on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigfloat/) which is a wrapper around [GNU MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/). But beware, it is currently declared at beta level and you must be prepared to build it from sources.

---

After @MarkDickinson's comment (he is the author of bigfloat), [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) is another wrapper around MPFR which is declared stable on pypi and is both richer and better maintained.

Comment: Speaking as the author of `bigfloat`, I'd recommend that people take a look at `gmpy2` instead. :-) It's better maintained, and does the same job of wrapping MPFR (and more).

Comment: BTW, do you know of any platform where NumPy's `float128` really is the IEEE 754 binary128 type (as opposed to double-double, or a zero-padded float80 type)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: thanks for your comment! I've included it in my post. Unfortunately I'm not a great numpy user...