# Is there a way for Python to read __float128 from a binary file?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I am trying to read a binary file that stores some `__float128` variables from other C project using Python.

I've been looking in the `numpy.float128` but it seems that it is implemented in a different way to the `__float128` in C.

Using the code below to read the same binary file gives me different number.

Python

```
import sys
import numpy as np

inFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
a1 = np.fromfile(inFile, dtype=np.float128)
print(a1)
inFile.close()
```

C

```
#include <quadmath.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    __float128 in_data;
    fread(&in_data, sizeof(__float128), 1, infile);
    printf("%g", in_data);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, your question is not quite clear. Your title question refers only to *input* and *output* of `float128` values. Do you also want to perform *calculations* on those values in Python (as you seem to say in the main text)? If so, what kinds of calculations? Have you looked at [Python's decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) or the popular 3rd-party [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) for the calculations? In what format do you want the `float128` values to be input from and outputted to?

Comment: I should also mention the [gmpy2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41985556/6246044).

Comment: I have edited my question. Is that making any sense now?

Comment: Yes, your question is now much more clear, both in file format and what  you want to do with the value. I'll not delete my comment so you can see the modules I referred to.

Comment: GIve us some examples of the different numbers.

Comment: See this discussion on `float128`.  Apparently it is just `long double`, not a true IEEE binary128,  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10288.  If the numpy dtype doesn't use the true 128 in calculations, there's little point in loading it.

Comment: Is there any other way to read in IEEE binary128 in Python?

Comment: @NewtonTang It doesn't matter if you can read it if you can't use it like 128bit floating point.